# Какая версия regex у locate?

Tags: linux, регулярные-выражения, поиск, bsd

Сталкнулся с проблемй поиска файлов `locate` с использованием ключа `-r,--regexp`

```
~$ locate --help | grep regex
  -r, --regexp REGEXP    search for basic regexp REGEXP instead of patterns
      --regex            patterns are extended regexps
```

Есть список фалый патерн которго в PCRE выглядит так:

```
'.*/[0-9]{1,3}-.{16}\.txt'
```

Примеры

```
~$ ls -gaG *-*txt | head
-rw-rw-r--. 1 0 Aug 13 21:32 100-gp9hQhTvaySlmrua.txt
-rw-rw-r--. 1 0 Aug 13 21:32 10-nvvYcrUpduSbWuaj.txt
-rw-rw-r--. 1 0 Aug 13 21:32 11-GEDkBMpKspWsdFu1.txt
-rw-rw-r--. 1 0 Aug 13 21:32 12-O2gSsKGP1KLl56ae.txt
-rw-rw-r--. 1 0 Aug 13 21:32 13-Q1dx492pLFGAiTTs.txt
-rw-rw-r--. 1 0 Aug 13 21:32 14-Lco6Gcisfl5QCvYG.txt
-rw-rw-r--. 1 0 Aug 13 21:32 15-kR75W2oeZ3PoibrE.txt
-rw-rw-r--. 1 0 Aug 13 21:32 16-QicUkZaseC5zr7p8.txt
-rw-rw-r--. 1 0 Aug 13 21:32 17-7ERZ7lnUX7RQQXZI.txt
-rw-rw-r--. 1 0 Aug 13 21:32 18-XbvGQcvrToIqNOSA.txt

~$ ls -gaG | head | grep -oP '[0-9]{1,3}-.{16}\.txt'
100-gp9hQhTvaySlmrua.txt
10-nvvYcrUpduSbWuaj.txt
11-GEDkBMpKspWsdFu1.txt
12-O2gSsKGP1KLl56ae.txt
13-Q1dx492pLFGAiTTs.txt
14-Lco6Gcisfl5QCvYG.txt

~$ locate 100 | grep -o 100-gp9hQhTvaySlmrua.txt
100-gp9hQhTvaySlmrua.txt
```

Обновил базу, пробовал найти с таким-же шаблоном, безрезультатно.

```
~$ time locate -r '[0-9]{1,3}-.{16}\.txt'
real    0m1.574s
user    0m1.567s
sys     0m0.004s

~$ time locate -r '*./[0-9]\{1,3\}-.\{16\}\.txt$'
real    0m0.168s
user    0m0.165s
sys     0m0.003s
```

**Вопрос**: какой тип движка регулярных выражений у `locate`?

Comment: `locate -r '.*/[0-9]\{1,3\}-.\{16\}\.txt$'`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew обновил вопрос, так же без результатов.

Comment: вы для начала убедитесь, что искомые файлы имеются в индексе: `$ locate 100 | grep 100-gp9hQhTvaySlmrua.txt`

Comment: @alexanderbarakin да обновил индекс перед тестами, добавил в вопрос возможную причину...  '-r,--regexp' - сокращенные патерны, '--regex' - полные

Comment: @Hellseher последний вариант должен быть правильным за исключением опечатки: `.*` вместо `*.` (т.е. `'.*/[0-9]\{1,3\}-.\{16\}\.txt$'`)... как справка и говорит, это старые ламповые basic-regexp'ы.

Comment: Вы и в самом деле не пытались использовать предложенное мною решение.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Да спасибо, вопрос правда разрешился в то же день, не было возможности отметить как верный. Тип регулярок схожий с Emacsовыми

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Здесь используется BRE POSIX:

```
locate -r '.*/[0-9]\{1,3\}-.\{16\}\.txt$'
```

POSIX BRE ("базовые регулярные выражения") отличается от синтаксиса большинства популярных библиотек регулярных выражений.

- Большинство метасимволов требуют обратной косой черты, чтобы придать метасимволу его специальное значение. Т.е. `/\([0-9]*\)/` = `/([0-9]*)/` в POSIX ERE. Большинство других разновидностей, включая POSIX ERE, наоборот, используют обратную косую черту для "подавления" значения метасимволов. Т.е. чтобы найти знак `?` в BRE POSIX, нужно использовать `/?/`, а не `/\?/`. То же касается символов `(`,  `)`, `+`, `{`, `}` 
  и `|`. В шаблонах POSIX BRE `a{1,2}` находит строку `a{1,2}`, тогда как шаблон `a\{1,2\}` найдёт `a` или `aa`.
- Имеется поддержка обратных ссылок только от 1 до 9. Например, `\(ab\)\1` находит `abab`, а шаблон `(ab)\1` неверный, так как в нём отсутствует соответствующая захватывающая подмаска.
- В POSIX BRE нет поддержки чередования (символ `|` обладает буквальным значением).

Comment: Спасибо, познавательно )