# Программирование на bash'e. Инструкция grep и регулярные выражения

Tags: регулярные-выражения, bash, grep

У меня есть задача, в которой нужно выбрать из системного журнала события ядра (kernel), сообщающие об освобождении более 1000 КБ оперативной памяти.

Немного моих начинаний:

```
journalctl | grep -P 'kernel:' | grep -P "[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][K][B]"
```

Я не понимаю как сделать чтобы было больше 1000 КБ. С использованием точки?

Comment: Я немного оптимизировал код
journalctl | grep -P 'kernel:' | grep -P "\d{4}[K][B]"

Comment: Используйте POSIX BRE, PCRE медленнее. `grep '\b[1-9][0-9]\{3,\}KB'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вам удобнее использовать PCRE, регулярное выражение будет таким:

```
\b[1-9]\d{3,}KB
```

См. [демо регулярного выражения](https://regex101.com/r/3wVHmh/1/).

**Подробности**

- `\b` - граница слова
- `[1-9]` - цифра от 1 до 9
- `\d{3,}` - три и более цифр
- `KB` - строка `KB`

Выражения POSIX BRE работают быстрее, поэтому я советую

```
journalctl | grep 'kernel:' | grep '\b[1-9][0-9]\{3,\}KB'
```

Тут `\d` заменено `[0-9]`, а `{3,}` — `\{3,\}`. О POSIX BRE можно ещё [узнать здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/959250/182013).

[Онлайн-тест](https://ideone.com/RN6UUh):

```
s="Some kernel: 10KB
Some  kernel: 10001KB
And kernel: 2001KB"
echo "$s" | grep 'kernel:' | grep '\b[1-9][0-9]\{3,\}KB'
```

Результат:

```
Some  kernel: 10001KB
And kernel: 2001KB
```

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> "[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][K][B]"
> ```

```
"[1-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][K][B]"
```

PS: Вроде ж очевидно?