# Sed замена на слов на другие значения

Tags: linux, регулярные-выражения, sed, grep

Всем привет. Делаю задачу 'заменить все почтовые индексы и названия их городов на 50-370 Wroclaw'
написал такую команду `sed 's/^[0-9]\{2\}[ -][0-9]\{3\}[[:space:]][0-9A-Za-z]/50-370 Wroclaw/'`

было  05-620 Karpacz 
 45-343 Waldenburg

стало 50-370 Wroclawarpacz  т.е есть лишние буквы 'arpacz' это проблема ну и в других словах тоже так (

Какую команду написать чтобы она еще удаляла лишние буквы в конце ( если они будут)?

Comment: Вы `\+` не забыли?

Comment: супер !!! забыл!)) спасибо )

Comment: [А что я говорил?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60810484/grep-how-to-write-a-postal-code-with-the-name-of-the-city#comment107589399_60810484)

Comment: Виктор прошу прощение я сразу не заметил ваш комментарий. Приношу свои извинения.

Answer (score 0):

У вас после `[0-9A-Za-z]` нет квантификатора, то есть находится только 1 цифра или буква. Чтобы найти 1 и более букв с помощью POSIX-совместимого регулярного выражения, используйте

```
\{1,\} # POSIX BRE: sed 's/.../.../'
\+     # POSIX BRE (GNU sed): sed 's/.../.../'
+      # POSIX ERE, sed -E 's/.../.../'
```

Параметр `-E` означает, что регулярное выражение написано с использованием синтаксиса POSIX ERE. См. больше информации о [разнице POSIX BRE и POSIX ERE здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/959250/182013).

Вы можете использовать одну из следующих команд:

```
sed 's/^[0-9]\{2\}[ -][0-9]\{3\}[[:space:]][0-9A-Za-z]\{1,\}/50-370 Wroclaw/' file > outfile
sed 's/^[0-9]\{2\}[ -][0-9]\{3\}[[:space:]][[:alnum:]]\+/50-370 Wroclaw/' file > outfile
sed -E 's/^[0-9]{2}[ -][0-9]{3}[[:space:]]+[[:alnum:]]+/50-370 Wroclaw/' file > outfile
```

См. [пример работы команд онлайн](https://ideone.com/a66gsw).